# How do I pass a variable or string or object into the backend in React?

Tags: reactjs, string, backend

So I'm trying to pass an object holding a string using a variable called place as you can see here.

```
const [finalOption, setFinalOption] = useState("")
useEffect(() =>{
        const place = {
            finalOption
        }
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/maps", place)
        .then(res => {
            setGooglePlaces(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])
```

finalOption is holding a string which I want to use later on on the backend right here using string concatenation in order for the Google API search to search up locations based off the string. The string in this case isn't important because it changes based on user input however the variable place that I made in the frontend is not defined in the backend and isn't being passed. Anyone have any ideas?

```
const string = place

module.exports.getAll = (req, res) => {
    axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${string}%20in%20Brooklyn&key`)
            .then(response => {
                res.json(response.data.results)
                console.log("google maps",res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).json(err)
                console.log(err);
            })
}
```

So on the backend I added in on line 2 a new variable using what I think is the body parser which seems to be working.

```
module.exports.getAll = (req, res) => {
    const string = (req.body.place)
    axios.post(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${string}%20in%20Brooklyn&key=`)
            .then(response => {
                res.json(response.data.results)
                console.log("google maps",res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).json(err)
                console.log(err);
            })
}
```

So another update the change in the backend is not working at all. Back to square one.

So I added in this console.log

```
const string = (req.body)
console.log(string)
```

and it returns to me as {finalOption : ''}. Its getting finalOption now which is good however finalOption is holding an empty string. I console logged finalOption on the frontend and its definitely holding a string. Why does it become empty on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send an object to the backend in the body. You should be looking at using a `post` instead of a `get`

```js
const [finalOption, setFinalOption] = useState("")
useEffect(() =>{
        const place = {
            finalOption
        }
        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/maps", place)
        .then(res => {
            setGooglePlaces(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I tried changing everything to post but on the controller side of things its just saying that place is undefined. Is there anything I need to add in the route itself? Here's what my routes look like.
```
module.exports = app => {
    app.post("/api/maps", googleMapController.getAll)
    app.get("/api/places", googleMapController.getPlaces)
}
```

Comment: Are you using express body parser middleware on the backend?@ErickMolina

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure what that is but I'm about to edit my question to show you what I added because now it seems to be working.

Comment: So, just to be sure, you've fixed your problem, right?

Comment: So it works but its not working. When I put in req.body.place it loads up the api but its not searching based off the string. the place in the req.body is still empty

Comment: When you console.log(req.body) what is shown?

Comment: Undefined. I'm definitely missing something else

Comment: Mnnn, I said log req.body, not req.body.place. Ensure you have this app.use(express.json()) declared before all your middlewares

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters to send the string to the backend

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/maps", {params: {finalOption}})
```

If you want to send the data in body, you should use POST method instead of GET

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/maps", {finalOption})
```

On the backend you can access it with `req.params`

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. I tried using your way with the params but the variable isn't defined still in the backend.

Comment: Variable is located in req.params

Answer (score 0):

So I kept messing around with it for another few hours and thanks to LordBee for pointing me in the right direction with the req.body I was able to come up with the solution. The useEffect on the front end was initializing before the useState was set so that is why it was giving me an empty string. So I put finalOption in the second part of the useEffect so that it runs it twice and gives me a complete string on the second run. On the backend side of things I was attempting to concatenate a object into the url not a string so I had to do a for(const property in object) in order to pull out that specfic keys value which in this case is finalOption and then assign that value to a variable which I was able to then concatenate it to the url. Sorry for the long message lol, thank you everyone for the help.